# EFI file structure

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, uefi, efi

I have system partition on my Windows 10 PC. It contains files

```
EFI
--Microsoft
----Boot
------bootmgr.efi
------bootmgfw.efi
------bootmgr.efi
------...other files
----Recovery
--Boot
----boot64.efi
--Dell
```

My C: drive also contains EFI folder

```
c:\windows\Boot\EFI\
------bootmgfw.efi
------bootmgr.efi
```

I select bootmgr.efi file when do boot order settings in BIOS.

But what all other *.efi files is used for? Why I have separate partition for EFI? Why my `c:\Windows\boot folder` also contains EFI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Windows 10 use a separate 100MB partition for UEFI since with UEFI it can read in the filesystem in C:\Windows\System32\winload.efi?](https://superuser.com/questions/1562855/why-does-windows-10-use-a-separate-100mb-partition-for-uefi-since-with-uefi-it-c)

Comment: That’s the original location of the files, from where they are copied to the actual boot partition.

Comment: @Daniel B You men `c:\Windows\boot\EFI` is copied to System partition?