# Faulty Windows 11 ISO

Tags: iso-image, windows-installation, setup

I downloaded a Windows multi-edition ISO from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows11).

I then flashed it to a USB drive using Rufus 20.0. Later, I booted it to Setup, with just having converted my SSD to GPT & formatting a partition to NTFS. In the part asking which partition to install Windows, if I select the empty partition I just formatted, & clicked Next, this will show:

**Problem #1:**
[image]

> It says at the bottom: We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files.

Clicking the format button on said partition would only show the hour clock cursor & then nothing would happen. Then the same prompt would show upon clicking Next still.

The only way to get through is to start the Setup with said partition unallocated or Delete said partition to become unallocated right at this point.

From here, one can either:

- Press New would create a partition fit for Windows & that is what you
  select, pressing Next. Although not without creating at least another partition, which is System.
- Press Next & the partition fit for Windows & the other partitions are created. Partition fit for windows is selected. This is process is not shown.

Basically, a partition can't be located, if there are no accompanying System partition & such. I find this setup of having extra partition annoying.

---

And yet this is not the real problem & only what compounds.

When I get to installation & when files have been copied to 81%, this pops up:

**Problem #2:**
[image]

> It says at the bottom: Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or missing. Make sure all files required for installation are available, & restart the installation. Error code: 0x80070570

The installation just stops there. I'm pretty sure the image I flashed to my USB drive is the unmodified copy of what I've downloaded from the link above. I've tried it on Rufus 20.0 & Rufus 17.0... It should work. I'm reporting 2 issues right now (though only the latter really maters) because they could be symptoms of the same malady.

Lastly, pardon that I do not have my phone to take decent pics.

AFTERTHOUGHTS: You guys think maybe Bill Gates is after me? It's very easy to hide scripts that if the client has my IP address, the server gives a different file.

UPDATE: I downloaded a fresh ISO & had another one created from media creation tool. Both ISOs gets past the second problem. So the previous ISO is to be blamed (as asserted by Akeo). Now, I would like to turn the attention to the first problem. I want to stop the need to have extra System partitions. Specifically because in my autounattend.xml for my modified Windows Setup, I specifically refer to C: & D: as partition 1 & 2. Having more partition throws the numeric off.

Comment: Seems to me it's a good hint and reason to download again.

Comment: Your partitions are too small for Windows 10 / 11.  Allow 100 GB for just Windows and inevitable updates and 250 GB for Windows, Updates and Programs.

Comment: I'm stretching what I have here. This machine only has 120GB.

Comment: I have seen similar errors since windows 7, do not format the partition you wish to install on, select it and hit delete (delete both if you do not need the smaller partition), it will now be unallocated space, then hit Next ( do not format) and setup should format it correctly and install windows.

Comment: You genuinely need a much larger drive. 256 GB would waste time in the long run. Get a 500GB drive and say goodbye to disk shortages.

Comment: @Moab I can maybe compromise on having little extra System partitions, but, like I said,  because of the second problem, it won't go through anyways.

Comment: “You guys think maybe Bill Gates is after me?” - Bill Gates hasn’t been at Microsoft for nearly 2 decades. As others have pointed out the targeted partition isn’t large enough to install Windows. Try deleting the target partition to confirm that the problem is a partition size problem. You really should remove the meta commentary from your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sorry my afterthought did no elicit an lol from you.

Comment: Actually when using Rufus, I tick the option to circumvent TPM, SecureBoot & enough RAM checks (at first, because the setup says I don't have enough RAM). That could simply be it.

Comment: @John I installed and have run Windows 10 quite nicely on a 50 GB partition (with no folder redirection outside C:).

Comment: Keep the RAM checks, but why didn’t you mention that fact in your question?

Comment: The first big update will probably run out of space creating Windows.old.

Comment: UPDATE: I downloaded a fresh ISO & had another one created from media creation tool. Both ISOs gets past the second problem. So the previous ISO is to be blamed (as asserted by Akeo). Now, I would like to turn the attention to the first problem. I want to stop the need to have extra System partitions. Specifically because in my autounattend.xml for my modified Windows Setup, I specifically refer to C: & D: as partition 1 & 2. Having more partition throws the numeric off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Windows 10 use a separate 100MB partition for UEFI since with UEFI it can read in the filesystem in C:\Windows\System32\winload.efi?](https://superuser.com/questions/1562855/why-does-windows-10-use-a-separate-100mb-partition-for-uefi-since-with-uefi-it-c)

Comment: Also highly recommend read: [Are GPT reserved and EFI system partitions important?](https://superuser.com/q/654798/194694) (shameless plug)

Answer (score 2):

> I downloaded a Windows multi-edition ISO from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows11).

If you encounter issues, like the one you report, you **MUST** validate that your download hasn't been corrupted.

The way to validate that your image is not corrupted is very easy (taken from [here](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_validate_that_a_Windows_ISO_is_a_genuine_retail_version)):

1. Open your Windows ISO in Rufus and click the `(✓)` button that you can see in the UI right beside the `SELECT` button. This will compute the MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256 checksums of your ISO and the one you are interested in is the SHA-1, so copy it
2. Go to https://sha1.rg-adguard.net and enter the SHA-1 you just copied (e.g. `c5341ba26e420684468fa4d4ab434823c9d1b61f` for `Win11_English_x64v1.iso`) into the search box, and click the search button.
3. If you do get a result (For the SHA-1 above, that would be `Windows 11 [22H2] v1 (x64) - (English)`), then it means that your ISO is a genuine retail Microsoft ISO, and that it has not been altered in any way.
   If, on the other hand, you do not get any result, then it means that the ISO you are trying to use is corrupted and you will need to both download and perform this validation check again until you get a match.

Now, if you find that your ISO is not corrupted, then, as others suggested, I would advise you to delete all the partitions from your disk during the installation process, and let the Windows installer create the partitions for you.

Comment: I know what checksums are, but in all my time downloading software that explicitly provides checksums in their site (such as FOSS), I've never encountered corruption. I never checked. I suppose error detection have always covered for me.

Comment: If you get an error that tells you that a file may be corrupt or missing, it doesn't matter whether you never encountered corruption before. But it's really up to you whether you want to carry out the steps that can help you troubleshoot your issue (by eliminating easy to validate potential factors), or just take a gamble on corruption not being the cause of your issue.

Comment: A more likely explanation is that since I was starting to swap the install.wim in Win11 ISOs, I may have also done so on the copy I intended to be original & unmodified (which was what's being tested now). Though I remembered being careful to keep it as is.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 2 is solved already – the ISO may have indeed been corrupt, or cosmic radiation flipped a RAM bit or whatever. It happens.

The situation with problem 1 isn’t entirely clear. I will assume that the two partitions filled all available space on the drive. This means there is no space for the *required* EFI System Partition (ESP) and also no space for all the other partitions Setup likes to create.

The ESP is a required part of the UEFI boot process. Like it or not, you’re stuck with it. The other partitions are not strictly required, but you may run into problems in the future or when Windows breaks if you don’t have them. You better incorporate them into your install script.

Make sure to also check out [gronostaj’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/654798/194694) if you’d like to know more about the boot process.

Comment: I have another Win11 ISO that is a REAL odd one. It boots only at l legacy mode. Then will only recognize partitions at MBR disks & then only will install in them. Otherwise will specifically complain about it not being MBR. One thing it does right is when there is a large enough, empty, formatted partition it installs there Windows & the ESP components, all in one.

Comment: Putting everything -- Windows, ESP; all-in-one. That used to be done back in Win10, I believe.

Comment: As for the odd Win11 ISO, don't ask how I got it.

Comment: No, Windows 10 and 11 have the exact same partition requirements. Also, you are confusing legacy booting and UEFI booting. Please read the linked answer.

Comment: I know the difference between legacy & UEFI systems. I'm just saying that this odd ISO that can install Windows 11 & ESP in a single partition (ala what I remember for Win10 back then & what I want now) happens to only work in the legacy system from booting only at legacy to demanding MBR disk for installation.